# cocoa sandbox get pid of connected socket client with port number

Tags: c++, cocoa, websocket, appstore-sandbox

I am developing a client server application in QT. I want to get the pid of client process who connects to server socket. I know it is possible with lsof -i:port number. But this is not permitted in Cocoa Sandbox. So i want any other way which is permitted in Cocoa Sandbox.

Comment: NSRunningProcess might give you the PID.

Comment: But i want to get pid of client process in server process not in itself.

Comment: how is the client launched? are client and server on the same machine? same user? do you need the PID before connecting?

Comment: Client is on same machine with same user. I want pid of client on first message from client.